# Why is multitouch not working with andengine GLES-2 SimpleBaseGameActivity?

Tags: android, andengine, multi-touch

Hi I'm trying to make a two player pong game but the Multitouch part of it is not working I know the device I'm using is Multitouch enabled so something in my code must be wrong. Right now i have two dedicated parts of the background that when touched set the paddle location but if someones finger is on the screen it won't recognize the second touch.

```
public class TwoPlayerMode extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private ITextureRegion mField, mField1, mField2, mField3, mPaddle;
private Sprite bottomPaddleSprite, topPaddleSprite, backgroundSpriteP2, backgroundSpriteP1, backgroundSpriteP3;
private String homelife, awaylife;
private int homeCount, awayCount;
Font mFont;
Text scores, lives;
SharedPreferences prefs;
MultiTouchController mtc;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    mtc = new MultiTouchController();
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final FixedStepEngine engine = new FixedStepEngine(new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera),60);
    if (MultiTouch.isSupported(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Multitouch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        engine.setTouchController(mtc);
    }

    return engine.getEngineOptions();

}



@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    try {

        ITexture paddle = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(),
                new IInputStreamOpener() {
                    @Override
                    public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                        boolean light = prefs.getBoolean("theme", false);
                        if (light) {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/paddle2.png");
                        } else {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/paddle.png");
                        }
                    }
                });
        ITexture fieldmid = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(),
                new IInputStreamOpener() {
                    @Override
                    public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                        boolean light = prefs.getBoolean("theme", false);
                        if (light) {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/fieldmid2.png");
                        } else {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/fieldmid.png");
                        }

                    }
                });
        ITexture fieldend = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(),
                new IInputStreamOpener() {
                    @Override
                    public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                        boolean light = prefs.getBoolean("theme", false);
                        if (light) {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/fieldend2.png");
                        } else {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/fieldend.png");
                        }

                    }
                });

        // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM

        fieldend.load();
        fieldmid.load();
        paddle.load();

        // 3 - Set up texture regions


        this.mField1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(fieldend);
        this.mField2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(fieldmid);
        this.mField3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(fieldend);
        this.mPaddle = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(paddle);
        loadFonts();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

}

public void loadFonts() {
    FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
    final ITexture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            getTextureManager(), 256, 256,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    boolean light = prefs.getBoolean("theme", false);
    if (light) {
        mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(getFontManager(), fontTexture,
                getAssets(), "plaincre.ttf", 40f, true,
                Color.rgb(0, 221, 255));

    } else {
        mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(getFontManager(), fontTexture,
                getAssets(), "plaincre.ttf", 40f, true,
                Color.rgb(0, 153, 204));

    }
    mFont.load();

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    final Scene scene = new Scene();

    topPaddleSprite = new Sprite(0, 195, this.mPaddle,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    bottomPaddleSprite = new Sprite(785, 195, this.mPaddle,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    // my spirtes and background
    /*
     * Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mField,
     * getVertexBufferObjectManager()); scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
     */
    backgroundSpriteP1 = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mField1,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager())  {
        boolean mGrabbed = false;
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()
                                    || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                                topPaddleSprite.setPosition(0f,
                                        pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - topPaddleSprite.getHeight() / 2);
                            }
                                this.mGrabbed = true;
                                break;
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                if(this.mGrabbed) {
                                    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()
                                            || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                                        topPaddleSprite.setPosition(0f,
                                                pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - topPaddleSprite.getHeight() / 2);
                                    } }
                                break;
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                if(this.mGrabbed) {
                                        this.mGrabbed = false;
                                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()
                                                || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                                            topPaddleSprite.setPosition(0f,
                                                    pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - topPaddleSprite.getHeight() / 2);
                                        }
                                }
                                break;
                }
                return true;
        }
};
    backgroundSpriteP2 = new Sprite(backgroundSpriteP1.getWidth(), 0,
            this.mField2, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    backgroundSpriteP3 = new Sprite(backgroundSpriteP1.getWidth()
            + backgroundSpriteP2.getWidth(), 0, this.mField3,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        boolean mGrabbed = false;
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                                bottomPaddleSprite.setPosition(785f,
                                        pTouchAreaLocalY - bottomPaddleSprite.getHeight() / 2);

                                this.mGrabbed = true;
                                break;
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                if(this.mGrabbed) {

                                        bottomPaddleSprite.setPosition(785f,
                                                pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - bottomPaddleSprite.getHeight() / 2);
                                     }
                                break;
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                if(this.mGrabbed) {
                                        this.mGrabbed = false;

                                            bottomPaddleSprite.setPosition(785f,
                                                    pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - bottomPaddleSprite.getHeight() / 2);

                                }
                                break; 
                }
                return true;
        }
};


    scene.registerTouchArea(backgroundSpriteP1);
    scene.registerTouchArea(backgroundSpriteP3);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionMoveEnabled(true);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    scene.attachChild(backgroundSpriteP1);
    scene.attachChild(backgroundSpriteP2);
    scene.attachChild(backgroundSpriteP3);
    scene.attachChild(topPaddleSprite);
    scene.attachChild(bottomPaddleSprite);


    awayCount = 3;
    awaylife = "3";
    homeCount = 3;
    homelife = "3";
    scores = new Text(50, 50, mFont, awaylife,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    lives = new Text(650, 50, mFont, homelife,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(lives);
    scene.attachChild(scores);

    return scene;
}

}
```

Here is a screenshot
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Looks like the problem described [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/multitouch/does-not-detect-multi-touch-t10116.html). There's no reference to `TouchOptions` in the posted code.

Comment: I've posted the comment as answer s.t. you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem described [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/multitouch/does-not-detect-multi-touch-t10116.html).

There's no reference to TouchOptions in the posted code.